# HTML printing paginate in some pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a problem printing documents.

I have to print a test, with a cover (full page), question pages with two columns (randomly generated), and an answer sheet at the end (full page too).

I needed to bring the page count ONLY in the question pages.

How could I do this, since page count methods were disabled in modern browsers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: P.S. If you do write that javascript code, please consider posting it yourself as the answer. That would help a lot of people!

Comment: Yeah, I will...
I just need to make it work exactly as I need. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a nice/easy way to add footers to html pages when printed right now, unfortunately.

And since you want page count on only a few pages, we've stepped into an even less supported twilight zone.

Basically your only option will be to write javascript that, when the user goes to print, will calculate page height/where page breaks will occur, and inject page count DOM in the correct locations.

Optionally, if these pages are dynamically generated, you could have the generator inject the page counts at the appropriate locations in the page (pre-calculated for standard page height). Hidden by default until a css print media query unhides them.